# Custom UISearchController Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

## The Bottom Line Question:

How do I override the default animation for the dismissal of a searchBar belonging to a UISearchController?

---

### Standard Search Controller Behavior:

Okay so I am trying to create a custom animation for when the UISearchBar that is attached to a UISearchController becomes active.  It seems the standard animation expects for the searchBar to begin with a width that takes up the screen.  When the animation begins it shrinks the searchBar and fades in a cancel button to the right of it.

### **What I want to Achieve:**

I want to have my searchBar begin in a small state, roughly half the screen width, to allow for two buttons to be placed in the navbar next to it as well.

#### *Present Animation:*

When the searchBar becomes active I want the animation to expand the searchBar and for the cancel button to fade in.

#### *Dismissing Animation:*

When the searchBar is dismissed I want the exact opposite animation to occur: Cancel button fade out and searchBar to shrink to it's original size.

---

### The Problem:

I have found a way to achieve the desired presenting animation by using a UISearchControllerDelegate method, presentSearchController:

```
func presentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    // Animate Buttons
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: {

        // First Hide Buttons
        self.createMoxyButton.alpha = 0
        self.centerMapButton.alpha  = 0
    })

    // Animate Search Bar
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {

        // Search Bar
        searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.wBounds - 40, searchController.searchBar.frame.height)
        self

    })

}
```

but I have not been able to achieve the dismissal animation.  I have tried using the didDismissSearchController: and willDismissSearchController: delegate methods but it results in weird behavior and does not use the animation of frames that I set in these respective delegate methods.  When the searchBar is dismissed it will expand to the full screen width, while fading out cancel button, then it will immediately change the frame of the searchBar back to the original size, ignoring my animation.  I have also tried using the removeAllAnimation() method to try and stop the default animation from taking place, but to no avail.

```
func didDismissSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    searchController.searchBar.layer.removeAllAnimations()

    // Animate
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {

        // Show hidden buttons
        self.createMoxyButton.alpha = 1
        self.centerMapButton.alpha  = 1

        // Search Bar
        searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.wBounds - 10 - self.createMoxyButton.frame.size.width - 20 - self.centerMapButton.frame.size.width - 20, searchController.searchBar.frame.height)
        self

    })
}
```

#### Image of Problem Dismissing SearchBar

Gif Animation begins with the searchBar in the Active state with the cancel button visible

[image: Gif Animation begins with the searchBar in the Active state with the cancel button visible]

Comment: Any luck on this one? I'm stuck here too.

Comment: @CliffW No, no luck trying to use the UICSearchController directly.  I tried many attempts, and they all failed.  I ended up using a UISearchBar itself which was easy to animate, I then had to hard code manually all of the methods that UISearchController offers to achieve to desired effect and functionality.  Sad thing is, we ended up pulling out this search bar from the project and opted for a different layout.... I'll have to dig through my repo for the code and I'll post up here soon as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Subclass UISearchController and implement the optional `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` 
method 
`- (nullable id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed;`

to return your animation object to do the animation for the dismiss.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot claim that this produces super smooth animation, but it doesn't look terrible and might be helpful (or even exactly what you need). If you want to try it out, you can create a new project (single view application) and just add navigation controller as the initial one and object of class `ViewController` as its root controller (just to quickly get the navigation bar). Code below is my whole implementation of `ViewController`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchControllerDelegate,UISearchResultsUpdating {

    lazy var createMoxyButton:UIBarButtonItem = {
        //customize this as your equire
        let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        return button
    }()

    lazy var centerMapButton:UIBarButtonItem = {
        //customize this as your equire
        let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        return button
        }()

    lazy var searchController:UISearchController = {
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self)
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        return controller
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [self.centerMapButton,self.createMoxyButton]
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        //this needs to be done because in shouldEndEditing
        //we need to set it to false to smooth animation
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems(nil, animated: true)
    }

    func searchBarShouldEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [self.centerMapButton,self.createMoxyButton]
        return true
    }
}
```