# Hide back button when searchBar is in use

Tags: iphone, swift, uinavigationbar, ios9, uisearchbar

I have a SearchBar in my NavigationBar. When the SearchBar is clicked, It should show over the "Back" button on the Navigation bar.

[Link to what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uUXe.gif)

So I want to hide the back button like in the image above but I am not achieving that the searchbar overlaps the back button. Can anyone please help

Here is my code:

```
class FirstSearchTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {


let searchData = []
var filteredSearchData = [String]()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for persons"
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal
        controller.searchBar.setValue("X", forKey: "_cancelButtonText")

        (UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self])).tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()


        self.navigationItem.titleView = controller.searchBar

        controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false


        return controller
    })()

    // Reload the table
    self.tableView.reloadData()


    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 14/255.0, green: 23/255.0, blue: 38/255.0, alpha: 1)

    self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red: 60/255.0, green: 69/255.0, blue: 83/255.0, alpha: 1)

    self.tableView.rowHeight = 80.0

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // 1 
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // 2
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        return self.filteredSearchData.count
    }
    else {
        return self.searchData.count
    }
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // 3
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredSearchData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = searchData[indexPath.row] as? String

        return cell
    }
}


func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    filteredSearchData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (searchData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredSearchData = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

}
```

Comment: how is it behaving currently image ink please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think these delegate might help you:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true);
}


func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated:true);
}
```

this link answer may give you some pointer [see implementation of above methods in link aanswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267162/custom-uisearchcontroller-animation)

Comment: Thank you very much! The link helped me a lot. Now it works for me